# How to create a heatmap with geometry node?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, geometry-nodes

I'd like to create a heatmap in geometry node from given points (vertex)

[image]

At first glance it looks like the GeometryProximity node could be useful, unfortunately this node is giving us distance cells

[image]

And in our case we would need a end result more similar to this below, where the distance to each points is accumulative

[image]

Any idea on how to do that, in 3D space, while keeping a non destructive geonode workflow?

Comment: would adding a colour ramp help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the cell separation from the distance output would still exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found a potential solution to create a field that represents points density, principle is quite simple, we snap points position and compare how many points are snapped at the same place.

procedural heatmap field on point domain:
[image]

problem:

- dependent on the snapping resolution, need a smooth function perhaps?
- snapping in voxel is not that great when with 3D point cloud, it will create artifact

Note that alternatively we could snap toward another mesh, here in our case a merged by distance point cloud

[image]

Comment: I'll mark this as a solution until someone has a more precise solution!

Answer (score 3):

Geometry nodes are not a good way to do what you want.  Any GN solution to this problem will be difficult to scale, and will only ever give vertex attributes, requiring an unnecessarily large vertex density on the rendering object.

The better way to do this is in the shader, with a point density node:

[image]

The point density node can be used in multiple ways.  Here, I'm using it to check the vertex density of an object ("Plane").  The density is checked for every rendering sample.

In this case, Plane.001, the object with the point density material, has only four vertices, so we can see the point density is per-sample, not per-vertex.

If we had an object with more vertices, and we really needed this as per-vertex data, we could bake this to an image and then to vertex color.  This kind of baking should be dealt with elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Thank you very much for this technique, unfortunately i need this information in geometry node and in real time, a baking workflow would be too destructive in my case. Nice to know that cycles can do it!

Answer (score 2):

I think geometry proximity node outputs "Max" distances. You need smoothed distances. Since GN don't have loops we have to calculate one by one.

[image]

Comment: what sense does the set position node make here?

Comment: Forgot to delete that. i was trying to displace it first :D

Comment: I see, so if i have one million vertices needed for my heatmap, with this technique i would need to separate each one of them and encode them one by one ?

Comment: Try this weird hack https://imgur.com/83ivzgM